# If one string matches at the beginning of last line in a specific file then replace the other string from same line.using regex groups?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file "test"

Below is the content

```
235788@@@235788@@@20200724_103122@@@SUCCESS
235791@@@235791@@@20200724_105934@@@SUCCESS
235833@@@235833@@@20200724_130652@@@FAILURE
235842@@@235842@@@20200724_132721@@@FAILURE
235852@@@235852@@@20200724_134607@@@FAILURE
235791@@@235791@@@20200724_105934@@@SUCCESS
```

if **last line** of this file begin with **235791** then replace string "SUCCESS" to "FAILURE" on just that line.

Expected Output

```
235788@@@235788@@@20200724_103122@@@SUCCESS
235791@@@235791@@@20200724_105934@@@SUCCESS
235833@@@235833@@@20200724_130652@@@FAILURE
235842@@@235842@@@20200724_132721@@@FAILURE
235852@@@235852@@@20200724_134607@@@FAILURE
235791@@@235791@@@20200724_105934@@@FAILURE
```

Below is the sample code

```
id = 235791
last_build_id  = `tail -1 test | awk -F'@@@' '{print \$1}'`
if (id == last_build_id  ){
    sed -i '$s/SUCCESS/FAILURE/' test
}
```

I would like to avoid these many lines and use one line shell command using regex groups or in any other simple way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` might be easier here

```
$ sed -E '$s/(^235791@.*)SUCCESS$/\1FAILURE/' file
```

you can add `-i` for in place update.

To pass id as a variable

```
$ id=235791; sed -E '$s/(^'$id'@.*)SUCCESS$/\1FAILURE/' file
```

you should double quote `"$id"` ideally, but if you're sure about the contents you may get away without.

Comment: how should I use variable for 235791. I cannot use  double quotes I need to put this in my groovy code.

Comment: @Bhargav please see the update, not sure why you can't use double quotes but this avoids it for the given input type. –

Comment: in my groovy script i need to use something like this **sh "sed -i '$s/SUCCESS/FAILURE/' test"** this is one line after validation in **If condition**  original post.

Comment: I'm not good at **sed**. May know what is **1** before **FAILURE** and does this command has validation as i requested **if (id == last_build_id  )** in my original post?

Comment: @Bhargav Of course, the replacement only happens if there is a match `\1` is to put back the capture group 1 in the output (the part in parenthesis).   However don't trust the comments and do your testing.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. You need not to use many commands for this one, we could do this in a single `awk` itself.

One liner form of code:

`awk -v id="$your_shell_variable" 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="@@@" } NR>1{print prev} {prev=$0} END{if($1==id && $NF=="SUCCESS"){$NF="FAILURE"}; print}'  Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file`

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v id="$your_shell_variable"'                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
NR>1{                                     ##Checking condition if prev is NOT NULL then do following.
  print prev                              ##Printing prev here.
}
{
  prev=$0                                 ##Assigning current line to prev here.
}
END{                                      ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if($1==id && $NF=="SUCCESS"){       ##Checking condition if first field is 235791 and last field is SUCCESS then do following.
    $NF="FAILURE"                         ##Setting last field FAILURE here.
  }
  print                                   ##Printing last line here.
}
'  Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** As per Ed sir's comment some `awk`'s don't support `$1`, `$NF` in `END` sections so if above doesn't work for someone please try more generic solution as follows.

One liner form of solution(since specifically asking it):

`awk -v id="$your_shell_variable" 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="@@@" } NR>1{print prev} {prev=$0} END{num=split(prev,array,"@@@");if(array[1]==id && array[num]=="SUCCESS"){array[num]="FAILURE"};for(i=1;i<=num;i++){val=(val?val OFS:"")array[i]};print val}'  Input_file  > temp && mv temp Input_file`

Detailed level(non-one liner code):

```
awk -v id="$your_shell_variable" '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="@@@" }
NR>1{
  print prev
}
{
  prev=$0
}
END{
  num=split(prev,array,"@@@")
  if(array[1]==id && array[num]=="SUCCESS"){
    array[num]="FAILURE"
  }
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    val=(val?val OFS:"")array[i]
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file  > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed

```sh
sed -E '${/^235791\>/ s/SUCCESS$/FAILURE/}' file
```

Or with the BSD sed on MacOS

```sh
sed -E '${/^235791@/ s/SUCCESS$/FAILURE/;}' file
```

---

When working with "the last X in the file", it's often easier to reverse the file and work with "the first X":

```sh
tac file | awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "@@@"} 
    NR == 1 && $1 == 235791 && $NF == "SUCCESS" {$NF = "FAILURE"}
    1
' | tac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v val='235791' '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="@@@" }
    NR>1 { print prev }
    { prev=$0 }
    END {
        $0=prev
        if ($1 == val) {
            $NF="FAILURE"
        }
        print
    }
' file
235788@@@235788@@@20200724_103122@@@SUCCESS
235791@@@235791@@@20200724_105934@@@SUCCESS
235833@@@235833@@@20200724_130652@@@FAILURE
235842@@@235842@@@20200724_132721@@@FAILURE
235852@@@235852@@@20200724_134607@@@FAILURE
235791@@@235791@@@20200724_105934@@@FAILURE
```